# What are the differences between classful and classless subnetting?

Tags: ipv4, subnet

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

ip: 10.5.2.1

subnetmask: 255.255.255.240

{10.5.2.1/28}

what is correct maximum subnetworks ???? 
What are the differences between classful and CIDR subnetting????

Comment: As the checkbox on top says Class A the answer is easy: There is one and only one network. Please try to solve your homework on your own!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference in how the two calculate the number of networks is that the classful calculation is based on the classful network. Based on the network range it falls in, the base network that is subnetted is 10.0.0.0/8, allowing for 1,048,576 /28 networks within it.

Based on CIDR, where classes don't exist, generally a tool like this will base it's calculations on a /24 giving 10.5.2.0/24 16 available networks.

As to which is correct, both depending on the context, but classful networking hasn't been widely used in networking for nearly two decades.

Comment: Good Answer.   On an unrelated note...I've always hated the questions that just asked for how many sub-networks, without explicitly stating the starting network size.  I hate having to *assume* the starting point.

Comment: On a tangential rant, when are they going to stop teaching classful networks? It's been obsolete for, what, 20 years?

Comment: Personally, I don't think they should stop teaching it, as it is a useful foundation for a number of concepts. However, I think the focus put on it needs to be reduced and it needs to be viewed as more historical/foundational rather than current.

Comment: I'd be curious what concepts you think are illustrated well by classful addresses?  As a historical note, sure it's worth learning -- along with Decnet, Appletalk, NLSP, and SNA.  There's no end to things you can learn that aren't used anymore ;-)

Comment: @YLearn //Based on CIDR, where classes don't exist, generally a tool like this will base it's calculations on a /24 giving 10.5.2.0/24 16 available networks.//
10.5.2.0/28 = 16 available networks ????

Comment: Based on the OP's question, yes 10.5.2.0/24 will contain 16 /28 networks.

Comment: @YLearn  are you can give some  fully example ??? {classful subnet vs CIDR subnet}

Comment: @Eddie sorry , starting point changed

Comment: @DinuthPerera I wasn't meaning your question specifically ;)  Just questions in general in the CCNA Knowledge/Academia world.  It was more of a 'tangential rant', as @.Ron put it.